# Websphere Liberty 18.0.0.3 MySQL data source object not injected

Tags: mysql, websphere-liberty

My    web    app    is    not    getting    the    datasource    which    was    configured    in    server.xml.    I    have    added    the    sqlconnector    jar    (mysql-connector-java-8.0.12)    under the folder `C:\wlp\usr\shared\resources\mysql`

server.xml

```
<!--    Enable    features    -->                
    <featureManager>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!--    Declare    the    jar    files    for    MySQL    access    through    JDBC.    -->
    <library id="MySQLLib">
      <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar"/>
    </library>
    <!-- Declare the runtime database -->
    <dataSource jndiName="AdminWeb/jdbc/AdminDS" transactional="false">
      <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
      <properties databaseName="admin" password="****" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="root"/>
    </dataSource>
```

DAO

```
@Resource(name = "AdminWeb/jdbc/AdminDS",lookup="AdminWeb/jdbc/AdminDS")
DataSource dataSource;

public UserEntity getAllUsers() {
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
   Connection connection = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("****************1");
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("2");
```

While invoking the webapp, the getconnection method throws

> [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.fist.tools.admin.dao.UserDAO.getAllUsers:25'
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataSource/server configuration itself looks fine.  @Resource can only be injected into web components/ejb components.  Does the class you are injecting into fit that description?

Comment: I'm trying to invoke a JAX-RS IBM webservice from JSP to display user details. The webservice  invokes the database to fetch the user records.

Comment: Is the `com.fist.tools.admin.dao.UserDAO` class a managed class though?  Managed classes include CDI beans, Servlets, EJBs, and JAX-RS resource classes

Comment: Hi Andy, The User DAO is a plain Java class that communicates with database.     Retrieving entity manager instance through the persistence context annotation like below                                                                                @PersistenceContext (name= "AdminWeb/jdbc/AdminDS")
 private EntityManager entitymanager;
       Do I need to add any other configuration other than the server.xml ?

Comment: That means your attempted usage is outside the bounds of the Java EE spec.  Please try moving your `@Resource` usage to one of the types of managed classes indicated by Andy or myself in our previous comments.  You can then have it pass the injected DataSource instance to your UserDAO.  Alternately you could consider if it makes sense to convert your UserDAO plain java object into a managed class, such as a CDI bean.